# Computing Colwise Means on a Given Interval

Tags: r, apply, mean

I have a data frame in R that can be approximated as:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:5, each = 4), y = rep(2:6, each = 4), z = rep(3:7, each = 4))

> df
   x y z
1  1 2 3
2  1 2 3
3  1 2 3
4  1 2 3
5  2 3 4
6  2 3 4
7  2 3 4
8  2 3 4
9  3 4 5
10 3 4 5
11 3 4 5
12 3 4 5
13 4 5 6
14 4 5 6
15 4 5 6
16 4 5 6
17 5 6 7
18 5 6 7
19 5 6 7
20 5 6 7
```

I'd like to compute colwise means at intervals of 5, and then collapse these means into a new data frame. For example, I'd like to compute the colwise means of df[1:5,], df[6:10,], df[11:15,], and df[16:20,], and return a df that looks as follows:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.2  2.2  3.2
[2,]  2.4  3.4  4.4
[3,]  3.6  4.6  5.6
[4,]  4.8  5.8  6.8
```

I'm currently using a for-loop as such (where temp.coeff would correspond to the "5" specified above):

```
my.means <- NULL

for (j in 1:baseFreq) {
  temp.mean <- colMeans(temp.df[(temp.coeff*(j-1)+1):(temp.coeff*j),])
  my.means <- rbind(my.means, temp.mean)    
}       
my.means <- t(my.means)
collapsed.df <- t(data.frame(colMeans(my.means)))  
}
```

..but I feel like there's an apply statement that could do the job a lot more efficiently. In addition, while the above data frame only has 20 rows, the one's on which I'll be working will have several thousand. Thoughts?

Many thanks in advance SO.

Comment: Do you want column wise means or sums? It looks like you calculated sums?

Comment: Oof! You're right. Allow me to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution with a combination of `apply` and `sapply`:

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) sapply(seq(1,nrow(df),5), function(y) mean(x[y:(y+4)])))
#       x   y   z
#[1,] 1.2 2.2 3.2
#[2,] 2.4 3.4 4.4
#[3,] 3.6 4.6 5.6
#[4,] 4.8 5.8 6.8
```

Edit after comment by @jbaums: depending on the desired behavior, you might want to add `na.rm=TRUE` to the `mean` calculation:

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) sapply(seq(1,nrow(df),5), function(y) mean(x[y:(y+4)], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Adding `na.rm=TRUE` to the `mean` call would ensure means are calculated for the last subset of rows when `nrow(df) %% 5` is not 0, although it's not clear what behaviour would be desired in those cases (or whether they might ever arise).

Comment: This is the solution I used. Many thanks! Works great.

Answer (score 3):

`aggregate` can do this if you aggregate against an appropriate running index.  You do end up with another column in the result (which can be removed).

```
aggregate(. ~ rep(seq(nrow(df)/5), each=5), data=df, FUN=mean)
##   rep(seq(nrow(df)/5), each = 5)   x   y   z
## 1                              1 1.2 2.2 3.2
## 2                              2 2.4 3.4 4.4
## 3                              3 3.6 4.6 5.6
## 4                              4 4.8 5.8 6.8
```

Comment: Here's a variation on this theme: `aggregate(.~idx, data=cbind(df, idx=((seq.int(nrow(df))-1) %/% 5) +1), mean)` It will work with the number of rows is not evenly divisible by 5; just the last group will have fewer observations.

Answer (score 2):

I really think `data.table` works great for situations like this.  It is fast and easy.

```
require("data.table")
dt <- data.table(df)

dt[,row.num:=.I]
dt[,lapply(.SD,mean),by=list(interval=cut(row.num,seq(0,nrow(dt),by=5)))]
#    interval   x   y   z
# 1:    (0,5] 1.2 2.2 3.2
# 2:   (5,10] 2.4 3.4 4.4
# 3:  (10,15] 3.6 4.6 5.6
# 4:  (15,20] 4.8 5.8 6.8
```

Comment: what if there are also a lot of rows?

Comment: Excellent point. Just changed the ```cut``` statement to handle lots of rows.